# How to check if the value exist in a field in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read the value of an field that i was getting from sp.
If the value was not there in the sp i getting the exception.
How to check if the value exist or not before reading the value. Below is my code.
I am trying the read the value of bid

```
With objCmdReq
.ActiveConnection = adoConnectionQuery
.CommandTimeout = 12000
.CommandText = "dbo.get_bid"
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@id", adVarChar, 
adParamInput, 32, strClaimFriendly)
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.Execute
End With


Set recClaim = New ADODB.Recordset
recClaim.CursorLocation = adUseServer
recClaim.Open objCmdReq, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

bid=recClaim.fields("bid").Value
```

Comment: Don't try to read the recordset if it is empty.  Check its EOF property.

Comment: What database, please?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we use ADO.net in vb.net. The following code should work for Sql Server.

I have used If Exists and the Select as parameter for Exists. It will return 1 for True and 0 for False. ExecuteScalar returns the first row, first column of the result set which is converted to a boolean.

This should be faster than returning Count(*) because it stops as soon as it finds a match. Of course when there is no match they will be the same.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strClaimFriendly = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Exists As Boolean
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("if exists(select 1 from YourTable where id = @ID) Select 1 Else Select 0;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strClaimFriendly
            cn.Open()
            Exists = CBool(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show($"Exists = {Exists}")
End Sub
```